# App Script last row items in multiple variables

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to get the values of the last row separated into multiple variables with app script.

**Example:**

```html
<div class="s-table-container"><table class="s-table"><thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:left">left</th>
<th style="text-align:center">center</th>
<th style="text-align:right">right</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left">One</td>
<td style="text-align:center">Two</td>
<td style="text-align:right">Three</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left">A</td>
<td style="text-align:center">B</td>
<td style="text-align:right">C</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></div>
```

**Expected output:**

Var leftColumn = A; 
Var middleColumn = B;
Var rightColumn = C;

I got the values of the last row with the following code:

```
var data = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of last row of the sheet, and want to put the values of columns "A" to "C" in the variables of `leftColumn, middleColumn, rightColumn, respectively.

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var data = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var [leftColumn, middleColumn, rightColumn] = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
```

- By this modification, the variables of `leftColumn, middleColumn, rightColumn` has the values of columns "A" to "C" of the last row.

#### Reference:

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)